# PHP-FPM child processes eating RAM

Tags: php, memory

I have a relative busy web server with Nginx and PHP-FPM, and after a upgrade to PHP 7.2 I have noticed PHP-FPM processes are eating all my RAM after some time.

The server is a KVM machine (Centos 7) with 32Gb of RAM and 8Gb swap:

```
[root@www ~]# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       32779736    18397204      239372     1508476    14143160    12417824
Swap:       8257532      167680     8089852
```

Here you can see the memory consumption:
https://justpaste.it/2vaqy
(I tried to paste it here, but Stackoverflow says my post looks spam)

As you can see in RSS colum, in 4th March each php-fpm process is using about ~1Gb of RAM, that makes a total memory comsuption (22 processes) of 22Gb.

Each PHP-FPM process ram usage is incrementing about ~300Mb per day.

This is my configuration:

```
[root@www ~]# cat /etc/php-fpm.conf | sed '/^;/d' | sed '/^$/d'
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
[global]
pid = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
daemonize = yes
```

```
[root@www ~]# cat /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf | sed '/^;/d' | sed '/^$/d' 
[www]
user = www
group = www
listen = xxxxx/php-fpm.sock
listen.mode = 0666
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.status_path = /xxxx-fpm
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log
request_terminate_timeout = 5h
php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = xxxx/php-fpm-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

This is my phpinfo:
https://justpaste.it/50zin

Any idea on whats going on?
Thank you in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This looks simple, if you have memory leaks, you must re-spawn php worker as many as possible, this can be configured with `pm.max_requests` option.

Start with 500, the more is the best performance you have but the more leak as well.